# Document base /home/ec2-user/myproject/web does not exist or is not a readable directory

Tags: java, tomcat, amazon-ec2

I am deploying my project to AWS with Apache Tomcat 7. I added the `ROOT.xml` into `Catalina/localhost/` like this

```
<Context
 path="/"
 docBase="/home/ec2-user/myproject/web"
 workDir="/home/ec2-user/myproject/work"
 crossContext="true">
</Context>
```

Starting Tomcat gives me the famous exception of Tomcat, but sadly, I cannot resolve it

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base /home/ec2-user/myproject/web does not exist or is not a readable directory
        at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:136)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:5247)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5436)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:679)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1966)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:473)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:622)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Things I tried:

- `sudo chown -R tomcat:tomcat web && sudo chmod 775 -R web` (Does not
  work)
- `sudo ln -s web /etc/tomcat/web` (Does not work)
- `sudo cp -rf web /etc/tomcat/web` (Work, actually, if I move the
  `web` folder anywhere outside of `/home/ec2-user`, it starts to work)

How can I make this work with the `web` folder under the `ec2-user`?

Comment: Maybe `/home/ec2-user` is belong to user who named `ec2-user`. User `tomcat` has no permission on the own directory of `ec2-user`. You can use ACL like this https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/91522/92059

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Edit `/etc/tomcat7/tomcat7.conf` from

`TOMCAT_USER="tomcat"`

to

`TOMCAT_USER="root"`

Not the best way, but I can continue my work now

Comment: DO NOT DO THIS. it's a particularly bad idea to run a web facing application add root. Imagine the impact from any security issue. Fix the root problem. (root here is not the user, although you could argue that out is somehow...)